# COALESCE(SUM(), 0) JOINED table column with GROUP BY not showing all results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a query that retrieves all reservations within a date timeframe and joins a payment table to calculate total payments, and few other things. The query seems to work just fine except it is leaving out reservations that have no payments. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    reservations.reservation_id ,
    properties. NAME ,
    properties.address1 AS prop_address ,
    reservations.last_name ,
    reservations.arrival_date ,
    reservations.departure_date ,
    reservations.date_created ,
    reservations.contract_filename ,
    reservations.contract_signed ,
    reservation_payments.date_of_payment ,
    (
        SUM(
            reservations.cleaning_fee + reservations.processing_fee + reservations.pool_heat_fee + reservations.special_fees + reservations.hoa_fees + reservations.rental_fee + reservations.taxes
        ) - COALESCE(
            SUM(
                reservation_payments.amount_paid
            ) ,
            0
        )
    ) AS sub_total ,
    COALESCE(
        SUM(
            reservation_payments.amount_paid
        ) ,
        0
    ) AS total_paid_to_date ,
    reservations.balance_due_date ,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT user_meta.first_name
                ORDER BY
                    associated_sales_staff.display_order ASC SEPARATOR ", "
            )
        FROM
            associated_sales_staff
        JOIN user_meta ON user_meta.user_id = associated_sales_staff.user_id
        WHERE
            (
                associated_sales_staff.reservation_id = reservations.reservation_id
            )
    ) AS sales_agents
FROM
    reservations
JOIN properties ON properties.prop_id = reservations.property_id
JOIN reservation_payments ON reservation_payments.reservation_id = reservations.reservation_id
WHERE
    properties.active_for_cleaning_schedule = 1
AND reservations.arrival_date >= "2017-05-15"
AND reservations.departure_date <= "2017-05-30"
GROUP BY
    reservations.reservation_id
HAVING
    (sub_total >= 1)
ORDER BY
    total_paid_to_date ASC
```

Comment: `HAVING (sub_total >= 1)` seems like a likely cause.

Comment: HAVING (sub_total >= 1) seems to be working properly. When I remove it I just get more results that include sub_total of 0. I'm trying to get results that include total_paid_to_date = 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was with the JOIN of reservation_payments table.

I updated From:

JOIN reservation_payments ON reservation_payments.reservation_id = reservations.reservation_id

To:

LEFT JOIN reservation_payments ON reservations.reservation_id = reservation_payments.reservation_id